# APNS Push Sound Files

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, audio, push

in my App I want to integrate some Push Notification Sounds, which the user can select.

My problem is to find soundfiles, I am not able to do it myself.

I searched in Google a lot, but I found nothing. Does anyone know where I can get some Push Sounds?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about [pond5](http://pond5.com)?